# Host Rest API Core on IIS without web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-config, asp.net-core-2.0

Is there a way to host Resp APIs on IIS without using web.config?

Currently, I'm working on .Net migration to .Net Core 2.1 and I realized that the .NET Core don't generate the web.config file, so I supposed it is not a good practice to add it. Following [this tutorial](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS), I have to create a web.config to host my application on IIS and I wonder if there is another better way.

Comment: A) No, the web.config is required for the handler to work. B) You don't generate anything, Visual Studio does that for you when you publish your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net Core may not rely on a web config depending on your selection of web server. That said; in certain cases, ASP.Net Core does rely on web config, particularly in new versions of .Net Core such as 2.0 or higher you may even need it for configuring max-size for incoming requests and responses (in early version it was configured in the middleware only).

Apart from this, the web config file is something that IIS needs in order to understand how to server the application/service. This means that even if you deploy a project without a web config, the moment it is started by IIS, that file will be created in its directory.

If you don't like it, you can run the project as a self-host app,or you may serve it using other tools such as PM2 (still will be run as a self-host app), or you may lunch it in docker it.

Comment: Thanks, @Transcendent, I think the docker approaches is the smart solution in this case.

Comment: "ASP.Net Core does rely on web config". No, it does not. The ASP.NET Core module for IIS relies on the web.config file. And the file is generated by Visual Studio, **not** by IIS. The version of ASP.NET Core or .NET Core does not change this.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Are you sure the file is generated by VS? Have you ever tried deploying a node app on IIS which natively lacks the file? I suppose your knowledge is outdated or maybe you don't know what you are talking about. Anyways, good luck.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Furthermore, an ASP.Net Core app without IIS, when lunched as self-host still relies on the web.config.

Comment: Are you sure of that? Just delete the file and see what happens, you'll be amazed. The web.config is an IIS file, not an ASP.NET Core one.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I suggest you to do this, make a dummy ASP.Net Core 2 app, try uploading a large file to an action api, do not configure the middleware, and instead put the config in the web.config file. If that fails, then come here and prove me wrong :)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: And run it as self-host mode. If you I don't see you here, then that means you comments here are of no value.